# Help Deadlock analysis

Tags: static, deadlock, crt

The Deadlock occurs in my application when initialization of  local static variable happens in the function called from DLLMain Entry point with param DLL_THREAD_DETACH.

Below is Windbg analysis

This is usually caused by another thread holding the loader lock.

Following are the Locks Held.

**CritSec ntdll!LdrpLoaderLock+0 at 7c97e178**

LockCount          3

RecursionCount     1

OwningThread       17e8

EntryCount         d

ContentionCount    d

*** Locked

**CritSec MSVCR80!__app_type+94 at 781c3bc8**

LockCount          1

RecursionCount     1

OwningThread       1100

EntryCount         1

ContentionCount    1
*** Locked

#

**Call stack Thread 17e8**

781c3bc8 78132bd9 0777fde4 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x46

00000008 b87d2630 00000000 MSVCR80!_lock+0x2e

0864ae10 08631d7f 0864ae10 EPComUtilities32!_onexit+0x36

0864ae10 b87d2588 00000001 EPComUtilities32!atexit+0x9

0777fea8 0864719f 08630000 EPComUtilities32!XCriticalSectionEx::ThreadTerminated+0x5f

08630000 00000003 00000000 EPComUtilities32!DllMain+0x20

08630000 7c90118a 08630000 EPComUtilities32!__DllMainCRTStartup+0x7a

08630000 00000003 00000000 EPComUtilities32!_DllMainCRTStartup+0x1d

#

**Call Stack thread 1100**

000000b0 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc

000000b0 ffffffff 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xa8

000000b0 ffffffff 06ce64e0 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12

000480ba 000f4240 00000000 CATSysMultiThreading!CATThreads::Join+0xf5

0012fcc8 00000004 00000000 JS0GROUP!CATLM::StopHB+0xf4

d138509f 00416694 00000001 JS0GROUP!CATLM::Unmake+0x6b

00000000 00000000 00000000 MSVCR80!_cinit+0xd6

00000000 0012fd6c 081e68d9 MSVCR80!exit+0xd

00000000 06d404f0 0998fb90 JS0GROUP!CATExit+0x1d

00000000 004ef366 0000000d DNBPLMProvider!DNBEPLMTransactionMgt::OnApplicationExit+0x229

00000000 0012fd9c 004eabfc JS0GROUP!CATCallExits+0x2bc

00000000 0012ff7c 0040cefd JS0GROUP!CATErrorNormalEnd+0x31
00000000 06ce71d0 06ce71d0 JS0GROUP!CATExit+0xc

00000007 06cdb120 059b61d8 DLMMfgContextSolver!main+0x146d

ffffffff ffffffff bffde000 DLMMfgContextSolver!__tmainCRTStartup+0x10f

#

***Please give you comments to understand what might have caused the deadlock.
Note: the moment i make the static variable as non static the problem disappears this  in context of example posted in forum [Deadlock occurs in Function Scoped Static variables (Thread Unsafe in VC++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339915/deadlock-occurs-in-function-scoped-static-variables-thread-unsafe-in-vc)***

Comment: Using global variable might solve, but i wanted to understand the problem. Why the local static variable initialization is leading to lock. 
As you see the call stack of Thread 17e8.
In the function 

void XCriticalSectionEx::ThreadTerminated()

{


const static XEPComBSTR bstrMethod =  __FUNCTION__;


}

While executing the above local static variable bstrMethod  initialization why the MSVCR80!_lock???

Answer (score 0):

In short, what caused the deadlock is that you did [something non-trivial in DllMain](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx).